# making an XML call to WhoisAPI

Tags: c#, .net, xml, whois

i just got an account at:

http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/index.php#/whois-api-doc.php?rid=1

ive never parsed XML with c#, how would i get the information in the `<email>` tag ?

Comment: Seriously use Google after looking at your profile most of your questions are easily answered with a simple Google Search:

http://tinyurl.com/y3kuuvs

Comment: Tigraine has a point; if you learn to Google up answers for yourself, you'll be a much more productive person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of three options:

- [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) (.NET Framework 3.5)
- [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(VS.80).aspx)
- [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(VS.80).aspx)

XmlDocument example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string email = doc.SelectSingleNode("/WhoisRecord/registrant/email").InnerText;
```

XmlReader example:

```
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)))
{
    reader.Read(); 
    reader.ReadStartElement("WhoisRecord");  
    reader.ReadStartElement("registrant");  
    reader.ReadStartElement("email");  
    reader.ReadString().Dump();
}
```